# Command which that isn't in norm

Tags: cp, which

I have this example

```
cp `which mv` rename
```

In instruction of my homework is, that this command isn't in norm and replace the command with different example that does do exactly the same.

My question is, what does it mean that command isn't in the norm?

Comment: Is that really what it says? If so, find better homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what this 'norm' means but the command itself is a little weird. What's the point of copying /bin/mv into 'rename' ? The command that does exactly the same is

```
cp /bin/mv rename
```

In case you didn't know. Everything inside ` is expanded so

```
`which mv`
```

produces (on some systems the output could be different)

```
/bin/mv
```

In other words. Everything inside ` gets called first and the result is substituded into the final command.

It can be any command you want so for example. I guess you are familliar with 'date' and 'touch' commands.  Let's say we want to create a file named the same as current timestamp. Command to get current timestamp is date +%s . Take a look at this example.

```
touch `date +%s`
```

Same thing but with different command inside `. ' date +%s ' is called first and the result of that is 1460885688 (yours would be different). After that the command that is called looks like this

```
touch 1460885688
```

Comment: What does exactly mean that command will be expanded. I am not really sure if I understand what this part of the command `which mv` do, specifically.

Comment: @inclooder On some systems, yes… unless you happen to be on a FreeBSD system where `mv` is located in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/bin/xpg4`.

Answer (score -2):

The command will not behave very graceful in case `mv` isn't in the current `PATH`.

I would suggest:

```
f=$(which mv) && cp $f rename
```